# mysqli_query does not return result

Tags: php, mysql, function, get

I code php to get returned from mysql.
My query works in mysql workbench, however it doesn't work in php.

sql below is returned well in mysql workbench.

```
"select * from players_info where name = XXXX and sex = X and season = xxxx and tName = XXXX"
```

My php is below

```
function player_info($conn, $name, $season, $sex, $tName){
    $output = '';
    $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM players_info 
        WHERE name ='".$name."' and sex ='".$sex."'
        and season = '".$season."' and tName = '".$tName."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result -> num_rows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $output = $row['name']."\n"
                ."No : ".$row['No']."\n"
                ."Pos : ".$row['pos']."\n"
                ."Height(m) / Weight(kg) : ".$row['height']. " / ".$row['weight']."\n"
                ."Born : ".$row['month']." ".$row['day'].", ".$row['year']."\n"
                ."Shoots / Catches : ".$row['shoots']."\n"
                ."Club : ".$row['team'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "no result!";
    }    
    $conn -> close();

    return $output;
}
```

HTML is below.

```
<div id = "player_page3">
    <?php  
    echo player_info($conn, $_GET["name"], $_GET["season"], $_GET["sex"], $_GET["tName"]); 
    ?>
</div>
```

I think my code returns 0 result even though sql is correct. 
What is the problem on my code?

UPDATE :

I added code shown below after $sql.

I think it returns nothing. 
result is "Error description : no result!"
'no result!' came from the else statement in my code.

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo("Error description : ". mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: why dont you use the mysqli_error like this . $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));   you wil know the error.

Comment: Where do you create the `$conn`? and how?

Comment: No idea where and how you're using the GET arrays and the return.

Comment: @David Winder  $conn is with in html! not put in here..

Comment: @JohnConde I changed like this "$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));", which does not give any error..

Comment: where is the $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** - as alerted in the comments you need to learn to prepare your sql statements. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - Your current script **IS VULNERABLE** to sql injects.

Here are some points to note:

Your `$output` variable is not collecting the result because it is overwriting itself over the loop. You need to change that to `.=`

```
$output .= $row['name']."\n"
    ."No : ".$row['No']."\n"
    ."Pos : ".$row['pos']."\n"
    ."Height(m) / Weight(kg) : ".$row['height']. " / ".$row['weight']."\n"
    ."Born : ".$row['month']." ".$row['day'].", ".$row['year']."\n"
    ."Shoots / Catches : ".$row['shoots']."\n"
    ."Club : ".$row['team'];
```

`.=` concatenates new text to the end.

**UPDATE**

If you want a single row you need to remove the while loop

```
if($result -> num_rows > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
    $output = $row['name']."\n"
        ."No : ".$row['No']."\n"
        ."Pos : ".$row['pos']."\n"
        ."Height(m) / Weight(kg) : ".$row['height']. " / ".$row['weight']."\n"
        ."Born : ".$row['month']." ".$row['day'].", ".$row['year']."\n"
        ."Shoots / Catches : ".$row['shoots']."\n"
        ."Club : ".$row['team'];
} else {
    echo "no result!";
}
```

Comment: Actually, the result is one row. however I don't know how to return just one row. So I used like that. I mean that is not a big problem so far. How can I change if I hope to result just one row?

Comment: and BTW as alerted in the comments you need to learn to prepare your sql statements. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - Your current script IS VULNERABLE to sql injects